# how capture subdomains in rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want redirect this urls:

```
http://tops.domain.com/test
http://files.domain.com/css/style.css
http://domain.com/test
```

to these:

```
/tops.php?what=test
/css/style.css
/index.php?username=test
```

I written this codes in .htaccess file and put it in root:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tops\.  [NC]
RewriteRule  .*  tops.php?what=$0  [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^files\.  [NC]
RewriteRule .* $0 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule .+  index.php?username=$0 [L,QSA]
```

but not work right

Answer (score 0):

Use this `.htaccess` :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^files\.  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tops\.  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tops\.php [NC]
RewriteRule .* tops.php?what=$0  [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !^username= [NC]
RewriteRule .+ index.php?username=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: no. your solution redirect `http://domain.com/css/style.css` to `/css/style.css` but I dont want this. I want only `http://files.domain.com/css/style.css` redirects to `/css/style.css` and your solution dont redirects `http://tops.domain.com/test` to `/tops.php?what=test` too

Comment: I redirect nothing (just rewrite). I don't understand: "I want only `http://files.domain.com/css/style.css` redirects to `/css/style.css`" because it's the same URI... if you try to redirect `http://domain.com/css/style.css` to `http://files.domain.com/css/style.css` you have to ask that in your question...

Comment: @Croises: I believe you just need to add `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^files\.  [NC]` just below `# skip all` line

Comment: @anubhava Thanks but I place before because I don't have to test real files for `files` subdomain. I even hesitated to remove it. But like it's not the right answer for OP...

Comment: Yes I agree I also don't understand all those `redirect` type comments.

Comment: @saeid There are 2 possibilities: 1) All subdomains share the same site (and .htaccess) and in this case `http://domain.com/css/style.css` = `http://files.domain.com/css/style.css` = `http://tops.domain.com/css/style.css` **or** 2) Each subdomain has its own website: But then you have nothing to do, unless you want to redirect, or prohibit, requests made to the wrong subdomains.

Comment: @Croises: for now I only want that rewrite `http://files.domain.com/css/style.css` to `http://domain.com/css/style.css` . can do this with **htaccess** ?

Comment: Certainly, there is nothing to do. Because `http://files.domain.com/css/style.css` is the same file as `http://domain.com/css/style.css`. Nothing to rewrite...

Comment: @Croises I want when user goes to this `http://domain.com/css/style.css` htaccess rewrites it to `http://domain.com/index.php?username=css/style.css` and when goes to `http://files.domain.com/css/style.css` rewrites it to `http://domain.com/css/style.css`  . ok ?